# How do I make this JavaScript countdown use UTC time?

Tags: javascript, date, time, timer, countdown

So I have this JavaScript and want to use UTC time.

I want to make it use "Date.UTC" but i'm not sure how to implement it.

So instead of this

> CountDownTimer('02/20/2016 10:1 AM', 'EST');

I want it to do this (UTC format)

> CountDownTimer('2015, 10, 10', 'EST');

Trying to figure out what I need to do to change it.

---

```
CountDownTimer('02/20/2016 10:1 AM', 'EST');
CountDownTimer('02/20/2012 10:1 AM', 'CST');
CountDownTimer('02/20/2012 10:1 AM', 'MST');
CountDownTimer('02/20/2012 10:1 AM', 'PST');

function CountDownTimer(dt, id)
{
    var end = new Date(dt);

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

            return;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = days + 'days ';
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var end_utc = new Date(end.getUTCFullYear(), end.getUTCMonth(), end.getUTCDate(),  end.getUTCHours(), end.getUTCMinutes(), end.getUTCSeconds());
```

And use the `end_utc` variable. However in this cases I would suggest to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) which gives you more control over your `dates`.

Also if you want to use the UTC function of date you can do the same as above:

```
var d = Date.UTC(end.getFullYear(), end.getMonth(), end.getDate(),  end.getHours(), end.getMinutes(), end.getSeconds());
```

This will give you the unix time (ms) in UTC.

DEMO 1 using first example : http://jsfiddle.net/4z5x6go5/ however you may notice that still the date you insert is though to be your local time and then it is converted to UTC.
DEMO 2 using moment: will take the input as UTC : http://jsfiddle.net/qzL4rpzg/2/

Comment: Could you give an example with the entire script? I'm pretty new to JavaScript and i'm still not sure. Thanks for the help.

Comment: DEMO 2 seems to input and output local time. It doesn't seem to do anything with utc. Trying to input and output utc using this format : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC